# Adding and removing applications in the side panel of pcmanfm

Tags: arch-linux, .desktop, pcmanfm

In Arch Linux, when I open pcmanfm, on the sidebar there are tabs called 'Home Folder', 'Trash Can', 'Applications', and 'Devices'.

Under 'Applications', there are shortcuts to a bunch of different applications, some of which I have installed and some of which I do not. It has entries like 'Accessories', 'Education', 'Games', 'Graphics', etc.

I am running Openbox, so do not have a lot of the config apps that LXDE might provide.

How do I change what applications appear here?

I have tried editting mimeapps.list files, I have downloaded lxmenu-data and tried to edit things that way. Is someone able to point me in the right direction? I have no idea where to even begin.